# WYSIWYG Editor Insert Image Browse Button not Showing on frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, wysiwyg, tinymce

I have a problem with insert image popup. The popup opens, but I can't see the browse button so I can't upload an image from frontend.
What can be the problem?

On phtml i have used below jquery to open tinymce popup.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
], function (jQuery) {

    var config = {},
            editor;
    jQuery.extend(config, {
        settings: {
            theme: 'advanced',
            theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,' +
                    'fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code',
            theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons4: null
        }
    });
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
            'short_description',
            config
            );
    editor.turnOn();
    jQuery('#short_description')
            .addClass('wysiwyg-editor')
            .data(
                    'wysiwygEditor',
                    editor
                    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add ***media*** or ***image*** to your **theme_advanced_buttons** option.

Example:

```
theme_advanced_buttons2: 'media,image'
```

Comment: No, I want a browse button which is visible in admin but not on frontend.

Comment: I don't understand your mind, can you explain more?

Comment: When we try to add wysiwyg editor on frontend, it will not allow to upload images in wysiwyg as frontend user does not have permission. So, for now I have override the image.htm file from tiny_mce lib and added my custom popup to upload image.

Is there any other way to do this in correct way?

Comment: sorry, I never try on frontend, I will try and if I can, I will update later